# Uniform convergence of $n\sin\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}$ on $[0,a]$ and $\mathbb{R}.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=n\sin\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}$. Prove that $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,a]$ for every $a>0.$ Is the convergence uniform on $\mathbb{R}$?

**Attempt.**  For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ constant we have:

$$f_n(x)=n\sin(\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}-2\pi n)=n\sin\bigg(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2\pi n}\bigg)=
\frac{\sin\bigg(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2\pi n}\bigg)}{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2\pi n}}\,\frac{n\,x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2}+2\pi n}\rightarrow 1\cdot \frac{x^2}{4\pi}=\frac{x^2}{4\pi},$$
so we are done with the pointwise convergence.

So far I am stuck on the uniform convergence, in other words how to prove $$\max_{0\leq  x\leq a}|f_n(x)-x^2/(4\pi)|\rightarrow 0$$ and $$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-x^2/(4\pi)|=\sup_{x\geq 0}|f_n(x)-x^2/(4\pi)|\nrightarrow 0.$$

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to offer you two different ways… choose which you prefer:

1.) Take $y \ge 0$ s.t. $$y^2 = 2\pi^2n^2 + x^2$$

Then $$x \ge 0 \iff y \ge 2\pi n$$

And we get: 
$$\begin{align*}\sup_{x\geq 0}\left|f_n(x)-\frac{x^2}{4\pi}\right| &= \sup_{y \ge 2\pi n} \left|n\sin(y) - \frac{y^2 - 4\pi^2n^2}{4\pi}\right| \\\\&\ge \sup_{\substack{y = 2kn\pi \\ k\in \Bbb N}} \frac{4k^2n^2\pi^2 - 4\pi^2n^2}{4\pi} \\\\ &=\sup_{\substack{y = 2kn\pi \\ k\in \Bbb N}}(k^2-1)\pi n^2 \\ &= \infty\end{align*}$$

2.) Another way: We have $$-n \le f_n(x) \le n$$ and so $$-n -\frac{x^2}{4\pi} \le f_n(x)-\frac{x^2}{4\pi} \le n -\frac{x^2}{4\pi}$$

Hence we can conclude $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f_n(x) -\frac{x^2}{4\pi} = -\infty$$

And so we get directly: $$\sup_{x\geq 0}\left|f_n(x)-\frac{x^2}{4\pi}\right| = + \infty$$

Comment: Very nice approaches! I am trying to see if some of your estimates would to the job for $[0,a]$, but it seems that the answer is negative.

Comment: Oh it does (but tbh I totally forgot to show ^^)… consider that we have to check for $$I = \left[2\pi n,\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2 + a^2}\right]$$ that $$\sup_{y \in I} \left|n\sin(y) - \frac{y^2 - 4\pi^2n^2}{4\pi}\right| \to 0$$ but $$g(y) = n\sin(y) - \frac{y^2 - 4\pi^2n^2}{4\pi}$$ is monotonous decreasing on $I$ by $$g'(y) = n\cos(y) - \frac{y}{2\pi} \le n\cos(y) - \frac{2\pi n}{2\pi} = n\cos(y) - n \le 0$$ with $g(2\pi n) = 0$… so we have:
$$\sup_{y\in I} \left|n\sin(y) - \frac{y^2 - 4\pi^2n^2}{4\pi}\right| = |f_n(a) - \frac{a^2}{4\pi}|$$ and the last term converges to 0 as you've already shown.